# A normal distribution conditional on $X_1 > x_1$ and $X_2 = x_2$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Suppose a random variable $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\theta =
\begin{cases}
h&\mathrm{with~probability~\pi}\\
l&\mathrm{with~probability~1-\pi},
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $\pi \in (0,1)$ and $h > l$ are known.
Suppose also
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
X_1\\
X_2
\end{pmatrix}
\sim
N
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
\theta\\
\theta
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\right).
\end{align*}
Then, what is the posterior probability $\Pr(\theta = h \mid X_1 > x_1~\&~X_2 = x_2)$?

I guess I should use Bayes' theorem, but I don't know how to use it if I have both an inequality condition ($X_1 > x_1$) and an equality condition ($X_2 = x_2$). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when $B,C$ are conditionally independent for a given $A$:

$$\mathsf P(A \mid B,C) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B\mid A)\,\mathsf P(C\mid A)}{\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B\mid A)\,\mathsf P(C\mid A)+\mathsf P(A^\complement)\,\mathsf P(B\mid A^\complement)\,\mathsf P(C\mid A^\complement)}$$

The complication is that one of the events has zero probability mass, so you will actually be dealing with its *probability density function*, but the formula is directly analogous.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to clarify one thing. Is it fine that both density and probability mass appear in one equation? That is, does the equation you gave remain true even it $\Pr(B \mid A)$ is replaced with a density but $\Pr(C \mid A)$ is probability mass?

Comment: As long as the 'dimensions' of the numerator and denominator are the same it is *usually* okay; it is essentially an application of l'Hopital's Rule.  Just watch out for the Bertrand Paradox and such.